# Grunt Sass - Compile all Sass files into CSS with the same name

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I used Compass and it compiles all Sass files into CSS with the same name. For example `my-style.scss` will become `my-style.css`.

All tutorials about **grunt-sass** that I found mapped the file name one by one, **manually** like:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: { style: 'compressed' },
    files: { 'css/my-style.css': 'sass/my-style.scss' }
  } 
}
```

Is there a way to make it more flexible? So I don't need to change the Gruntfile whenever I have new Sass file.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this format for specifying your source and destination files:

```
    sass: {
        src: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'source/styles/',
                src: ['**/*.scss'],
                dest: 'destination/styles/',
                ext: '.css'
            }]
        }
    }
```

This reads as "take all files matching `*.scss` in `source/styles/` and its subfolders, process them and put them into `destination/styles/`, changing extension to `.css`. See also http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically

Comment: Thanks for this. it works but why there's a `.map` file compiled into the destination folder? So the results are two files: `my-style.css` and `my-style.css.map`?

Comment: Nevermind, it's because I add `sourceMap: true` to the `options`

Comment: Keep in mind that this syntax is not something specific to grunt-scss or any other plugin, this is a native feature of grunt. I have added a link to the documentation page.

Comment: Anyone know how to do this but with multiple source and destination dirs? I have: dirApples & dirPears & dirGrapes, each contianing the same subdir structure, and I want to find each scss:
`dirApples> sub1/css/file.scss, dirApples/sub2/css/name.scss  && dirPears> sub1/css/file.scss, dirPears/sub2/css/name.scss `. 
I want to grab all those scss files and output css in the same dirs with the file names correct. Every example I see, like the answer above from teh docs, has a single destination.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the universal notation:

```
sass: {
  dist: {
    options: { style: 'compressed' },
    files: { 'css/*/**.css': 'sass/my-style.scss' }
  } 
}
```

In this case, the Grunt will go for all *.css files inside the `css` folder (including subfolders) regardless of the file name, and compile to `my-style.scss`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want the compiled to be same name as the original. Also I have more than one Sass files that I need to be separated (so no @import)